# Have Winglings, Obsidimen and T'skrang appeared in Shadowrun?

Tags: shadowrun

In the Forth World/Earthdawn three additional races were present, Windlings, Obsidimen and T'skrang.

I know that Windlings have been widely regarded as [Pixies](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Pixie) but have the other two races appeared in canon in Shadowrun at all?

Answer (score 8):

> *Evo* share holder *Hideo Yoshida* may be an obsidiman.

- [Obsidimen: Shadowrun.wikia](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Obsidiman)

> No t'skrangs have been reported in the Sixth World (Shadowrun).

- [T'skrang: Shadowrun.wikia](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/T%27skrang)

I've found this wikia site rather reliable so far - but, of course, I might be wrong, and other answers may provide more up to date and more precise information.

Answer (score 1):

In *Artifacts Unbound*, page 34, there is a changeling named Simon Andrews who looks basically like a t'skrang. He works directly for the dragon Lofwyr.